# Сборка Docker-образа с копированием всех *.csproj

Tags: c#, .net, docker

Доброе время суток.

У меня имеется солюшн со множеством проектов на .net 5, среди них микросервисы и зависимые проекты.
Я пытаюсь оптимизировать сборку образов как в [гайде](https://docs.docker.com/samples/dotnetcore/#create-a-dockerfile-for-an-aspnet-core-application), но там  показан слишком простой пример.

В моём случае имеется корневая папка солюшена с расположенными в разных подпапках проектами. Мне нужно копировать все `*.csproj` с сохранением структуры вложенностей, указав некую корневую папку источника.

**Вопрос: как при помощи инструкций `Dockerfile` можно копировать все `*.csproj` из разных подпапок, сохраняя при этом структуру?**

- Вариант `COPY . .` работает, но приводит к тому, что тяжелая и долгая операция `dotnet restore` будет запускаться каждый раз при постройке образа.
- Вручную указывать полные пути всех *.csproj для копирования усложнит
  dockerfile и потенциально приведет к ошибкам и упущениям.

Comment: Наверное вам следует воспользоваться vcs. Все тяжелые и долгие операции естественно будут запускаться каждый раз при создании нового образа.

Answer (score 0):

Один способ это сделать - использовать кодогенерацию.

То есть создайте шаблон `Dockerfile`-а и простой скрипт, который по шаблону сгенерирует конечный `Dockerfile` с нужными командами `COPY path/to/proj.csproj path/to/proj.csproj` для каждого нужного файла `*.csproj` в дереве.